# How to create an image gallery in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming, media

I would like to create image galleries in my Drupal 7 site. Ideally the gallery should be easy to create and themable. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Here is a brand new video tutorial to walk you through how to do everything http://geoffhankerson.com/node/173

Comment: I converted the accepted answer to a comment, as the link appears to be broken w/o a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like Taxonomy, Colorbox, Views, and the Image field in D7 would be the best way to do it.

1. Create a taxonomy for gallery
2. Create a content type for image
3. Create a View to display the gallery taxonomy
4. Create a View to display the images in the gallery taxonomy term

I say that is the best approach because it gives you the most flexibility, and will only take you about 30 minutes to set up. Anything else for a gallery (in my experience) tends to be overkill unless you're an actual photo sharing website.

Answer (score 3):

[Media Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/media_gallery) is your friend.

Comment: This looks promising -- thanks for the pointer!  Any current concerns about stability (cf. the comment about "not for production sites unless..." on the module page)?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create gallery is to use Views module.

Simply create a new content type (name it as gallery_image) with a CCK image field.

Define image styles (presents) for thumbnail and preview sizes. (example.com/admin/config/media/image-styles)

Create a view of type node, filter item with respect to type gallery_image and status published.

Use Views' templates to override each image and whole views layout.

---

For multiple galleries.

Create a content type and name it as gallery.

Add a CCK image field (For mega upload use [Image FUpload](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/image_fupload&rct=j&q=Image%20FUpload&ei=eYQHTuzgMJHz-gayx5yoAw&usg=AFQjCNG3H1mQIQbKJ_8jMCENLrbmJAiGog&sig2=1p2wJNpUOUL7xSuD_qDWvQ&cad=rja))

While settings the CCK image field, set number of upload items as unlimited or more than 1 as you like.

Create image style (pre-sets) for thumbnail and preview sizes.

Setup your node--content-type.tpl.php template to customise gallery layout.

Comment: I think my problem with this approach is that I am going to be creating many different galleries, so how do I tell Drupal that images X, Y, Z belong to one gallery while images A, B, C belong to a different one?

Answer (score 0):

The [Fancybox](http://drupal.org/project/fancybox) module is a very good one for creating your own gallery, and it is very simple to use as well.

> Provides the [Fancybox jQuery plugin](http://www.fancybox.net/) for displaying images (HTML content and
>   multimedia support will come) in an elegant box.
>
> This module requires Fancybox 1.3+ ([1.3.1 is recommended](http://code.google.com/p/fancybox/downloads/list)).

Answer (score -1):

The [Views Galleriffic](https://drupal.org/project/views_galleriffic) module is fantastic.

> This is a views integration for the [Galleriffic JQuery](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/) plugin.
>
> It allows you to make Views with image fields to create a galleries. These galleries can be attached to nodes themselves or act as stand-alone galleries. Because it uses Views this module is extremely flexible.